# Testing channels 2.0 with pytest-asyncio getting RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, django-channels

I'm trying to test new `channels` 2.0 with `pytest-asyncio` (0.8.0). If I place different assertions in the same function like:

```
import json
import pytest
from concurrent.futures._base import TimeoutError
from channels.testing import WebsocketCommunicator
from someapp.consumers import MyConsumer


@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def setup_database_and_websocket():
    path = 'foo'
    communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(MyConsumer, path)
    connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
    assert connected
    return communicator


@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_1_and_2():
    communicator = await setup_database_and_websocket()
    sent = json.dumps({"message": 'abc'})
    await communicator.send_to(text_data=sent)
    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
        await communicator.receive_from()
    await communicator.send_input({
        "type": "websocket.disconnect",
        "code": 1000,
    })

    communicator = await setup_database_and_websocket()
    sent = json.dumps({"message": 1})
    await communicator.send_to(text_data=sent)
    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
        await communicator.receive_from()
    await communicator.send_input({
        "type": "websocket.disconnect",
        "code": 1000,
    })
```

then I'm not getting an error. But if I separate test cases like:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_1():
    communicator = await setup_database_and_websocket()
    sent = json.dumps({"message": 'abc'})
    await communicator.send_to(text_data=sent)
    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
        await communicator.receive_from()
    await communicator.send_input({
        "type": "websocket.disconnect",
        "code": 1000,
    })


@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_2():
    communicator = await setup_database_and_websocket()
    sent = json.dumps({"message": 1})
    await communicator.send_to(text_data=sent)
    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
        await communicator.receive_from()
    await communicator.send_input({
        "type": "websocket.disconnect",
        "code": 1000,
    })
```

then I'm getting following error upon the second `receive_form` call:

```
with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
>           await communicator.receive_from()

someapp/tests/test_consumers_async.py:106: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/testing/websocket.py:71: in receive_from
response = await self.receive_output(timeout)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/testing.py:66: in receive_output
self.future.result()
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py:54: in __call__
await await_many_dispatch([receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py:48: in await_many_dispatch
await dispatch(result)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:95: in __call__
return await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py:339: in wait_for
return (yield from fut)
/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py:56: in run
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/db.py:13: in thread_handler
return super().thread_handler(loop, *args, **kwargs)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:110: in thread_handler
return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py:99: in dispatch
handler(message)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py:19: in websocket_connect
self.connect()
someapp/consumers.py:22: in connect
self.group_name, self.channel_name)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:49: in __call__
return call_result.result()
/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py:432: in result
return self.__get_result()
/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py:384: in __get_result
raise self._exception
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:63: in main_wrap
result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py:290: in group_add
await connection.expire(group_key, self.group_expiry)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py:152: in __exit__
self._release_callback(conn)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/pool.py:361: in release
conn.close()
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py:352: in close
self._do_close(ConnectionForcedCloseError())
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py:359: in _do_close
self._writer.transport.close()
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py:621: in close
self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:574: in call_soon
self._check_closed()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True debug=False>

def _check_closed(self):
if self._closed:
>           raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
E           RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:357: RuntimeError
```

Also if I do (as in https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html):

```
await communicator.disconnect()
```

instead of:

```
await communicator.send_input({
    "type": "websocket.disconnect",
    "code": 1000,
})
```

then the following error is raised:

```
>       await communicator.disconnect()

someapp/tests/test_consumers_async.py:96: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/testing/websocket.py:100: in disconnect
    await self.future
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py:54: in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch([receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py:48: in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:95: in __call__
    return await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py:339: in wait_for
    return (yield from fut)
/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py:56: in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/db.py:13: in thread_handler
    return super().thread_handler(loop, *args, **kwargs)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:110: in thread_handler
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
../../../.virtualenvs/some_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py:99: in dispatch
    handler(message)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <someapp.consumers.ChatConsumer object at 0x7f38fcc55240>
message = {'code': 1000, 'type': 'websocket.disconnect'}

    def websocket_disconnect(self, message):
        """
            Called when a WebSocket connection is closed. Base level so you don't
            need to call super() all the time.
            """
        # TODO: group leaving
>       self.disconnect(message["code"])
E       TypeError: disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What should I do to separate those test cases in the respective individual test functions?

---

Edit: disconnect error is a trivial one - I forgot to add that positional argument (`code`) in subclassed method:

```
def disconnect(self, code):
    AsyncToSync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)('foo', self.channel_name)
```

---

Edit2: It [was a bug](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/908) related to redis channel - bugfix is in the latest `channels` and `asgiref` master branches on github.

Comment: I guess maybe it could the global connection or global event loop, you can try `pytestmark = pytest.mark.asyncio(forbid_global_loop=True)` and I wonder if there is sth similar in djangodb

Comment: No improvements; I'm afraid that is deprecated (["The forbid_global_loop parameter has been removed."](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-asyncio)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? (I didn't test it though.)

```
@pytest.fixture
async def communicator(db):
    path = 'foo'
    communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(MyConsumer, path)
    connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
    assert connected
    return communicator


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_1(communicator):
    sent = json.dumps({"message": 'abc'})
    await communicator.send_to(text_data=sent)
    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
        await communicator.receive_from()
    await communicator.send_input({
        "type": "websocket.disconnect",
        "code": 1000,
    })


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_2(communicator):
    sent = json.dumps({"message": 1})
    await communicator.send_to(text_data=sent)
    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
        await communicator.receive_from()
    await communicator.send_input({
        "type": "websocket.disconnect",
        "code": 1000,
    })
```

Comment: I'm kind of allowed to separate test cases with this approach (slightly modified), but my testing code doesn't work as it should. Maybe I should play with `event_loop` fixture to solve this. I'll comment here if and when I'm done...